# How to convert a string like ["8","14","22"] into an array?

Tags: php

I have a string like this:
["8","14","22"]
how can I turn that into an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens to be in JSON format, so use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$str = '["8","14","22"]';

$arr = json_decode($str);

print_r($arr);

// Output:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 8
//     [1] => 14
//     [2] => 22
// )
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as:

```
$string = '["8","14","22"]';
json_decode($string);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about php. then you would use the function implode:

```
$string = '"8","14","xx"'
$arr = implode(",",$string);
```